# Ramda zipWith, one argument

Tags: ramda.js

A function for telling if a person has any given pets.

```
const person = {
  name: 'joe',
  pets: {
    dog: true,
    cat: false,
    fish: true
  }
}

const personHasPet = (pet: string) => R.pipe(R.path('pets', pet), R.equals(true));

const personHasPets = (listOfPets: string[]) => R.allPass(R.zipWith(personHasPet, listOfPets, listOfPets))(person);
```

This works. However, as you can see, I supply `zipWith` with two arguments. Thats because zipWith requires two argument. Why is this?

I only need one since I only have one argument in `persHasPet` function. `zipWith` always requires two? Why is this? Is there any other function when you have one argument? And another when you have three? Makes no sense.

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish with `zipWith`, but the function supplied is definitely designed for working with two lists, and the callback should definitely take two parameters.  Thus:

```js
zipWith(fn, [a1, a2, a3, ... an], [b1, b2, b3, ... bn])
//=> [fn(a1, b1), fn(a2, b2), fn(a3, b3), ... fn(an, bn)]
```

This is what it does, "zipping" together two lists by applying a function to each pair.

I think the code you're looking for might be something like the following, but I'm not really certain:

```js
const personHasPet = compose (path, flip (append) (['pets']) )
const personHasPets = compose (allPass, map (personHasPet) )

const joe = {name: 'joe', pets: {dog: true, cat: false, fish: true}}

console .log (
  personHasPet ('dog') (joe),             //=> true
  personHasPet ('cat') (joe),             //=> false
  personHasPet ('fish') (joe),            //=> true
)

console .log (
  personHasPets (['dog', 'cat']) (joe),   //=> false
  personHasPets (['dog', 'fish']) (joe),  //=> true
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {compose, path, flip, append, allPass, map} = R        </script>
```

I'm also not sure if that Ramda implementation gains anything over the vanilla

```js
const personHasPet = (pet) => (person) => person .pets && person .pets [pet]
```

Comment: For readability I would like to have pets (['dog', 'cat']) as an argument in the function (extra helpful with typescript), hence my try with zipObj. Anyway to do a personHasPets = (pets) => R... ?

Comment: @Joe: So you're looking for an impure function that makes reference to something outside its parameters (i.e., `person`)?  Ramda is designed for a different style of coding.  But if you could certainly write `const hasPet = (person) => (pet) => person.pets && person.pets[pet]`, and partially apply `person` to it to get `personHasPet`, then do something similar with the plural.

Comment: Hm. Ok. But how do my colleagues (or me after a week) know what to supply different functions with? It's not obvious the personHasPets should be supplied with an array of strings and then the person object. I thought you only left out the "main" data object in functional programming. Is standard procedure to check the tests before implementing a function?

Comment: I usually annotate with signatures.  (`// hasPet :: Person -> String -> Boolean`).  You need to decide for yourself what is "the main data object".  I assumed that both pets and a person would be equally likely to change.  If you're more likely to want to call multiple times with the same person and different lists of pets, then I would reverse the parameter order.  And I didn't follow your question about tests.